# Given a png monochrome line drawing, how to darken only lines that are a certain distance away from other lines?

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I have a png image that I generated from a cad drawing using edge-detection. Only problem is all the lines have the same thickness. The lines that mark the main edges I need to be thicker and more prominent. But, I also have shading-type lines in the same drawing, that I do not want to be any thicker, as then they would merge together.

I am using imagemagick, and using `-morphology dilate disk:2` worked to make all the lines thicker. However, now the shading lines are too thick and they merged into a blob.

How can I thicken only the lines that are not the shading lines? I'm thinking that the shading lines may be identifiable by their proximity to each other. Maybe I could use that as a metric to create a mask that can identify the not-shading lines for thickening. Does this sound like it could work, or is there some other suggestion? If so, how could this be done using imagemagick (or similar)?

---

EDIT:

I made a sample model to demonstrate the effects that I've described.

First, here is the line drawing **without** darkening (so thinner lines) (made from imagemagick's edge-detection of the exported png):

[image: undarkened line drawing]

And second, here is the line drawing **with** darkening (so thicker lines) (the previous one but with an additional `-morphology dilate disk:2` step).

[image: darkened line drawing]

The first drawing is too faint, it hurts my eyes to look at. The second one is pretty good, almost good enough, but the shading lines (on the two crossed cylinders) are too prominent, I think. I thought I might be able to get the best of both worlds by darkening only the non-shading lines.

Comment: It would help to see the image in question. But just reading your description it sounds a bit far fetched. You might be able to get close, but then you'll probably have some places where the method fails. Where lines meet for example. It would be so much easier to work with the original working file first or an exported vector file if that's possible.

Comment: @Wolff thank you for the helpful feedback. The original image is proprietary so I am not able to share it, but it came from a png exported by openscad. I looked into how to project a vector graphic from openscad, but could not get it to create the perspective views needed, e.g. with lines hidden when they occur behind other objects in view. The png exported and then altered by imagemagick is close to the line drawing I need, though. Perhaps what I have so far, some flooded shading notwithstanding, will have to be good enough, if the additional mod that I've described here seems too far-fetched

Comment: Well, it's not a standard way of working. More like a hack. So if it could be done really depends on how the image looks. If it's a really simple image, you could do [something like this](https://i.imgur.com/Mnti8Hx.gif) in Photoshop (or similar program). But if thick and thin lines meet in many different ways I can't see how the software should be able to understand the difference.

Comment: Need to see something to be honest. If you can't share the specific image, then something similar would be fine.  But there is nothing that can do what you want really. To make different lines darker you would need to select those parts if the image, and apply something like a levels adjustment. Raster software like GIMP or imagemagick have no way of knowing how close one line is to another.

Comment: These kinds of software know nothing about lines or what different parts of an image are.  Another possibility is to change the line thickness in your CAD software before exporting, or export to a vector image format, and edit the strokes in vector software. GIMP isn't vector software.

Comment: @BillyKerr, only way for the software to know about how close lines are would be to blur the image and perhaps use that as a mask? Then the shading lines would become gray areas with the right blur radius. But it would also blur the other lines so ...

Comment: @Wolff - yes there could be ways/hacks to try to separate the different lines in some way, but it's not going to be easy. Even harder to make suggestions with nothing to see.

Comment: If you could export an image with shading lines and another image without them, you could make the lines thicker on the latter and combine it with the first. Probably using blend mode "multiply" would be fine.

Comment: you can stack the two views easily even probably in the cad application itself.  ive done this atleast in Creo, NX and solidworks before. But if you stack externally you can even stack it with a external render. athis is known as compositing in the 3D graphics industry and its done really really often.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful advice. @BillyKerr I've created (& added to my question above) a couple of sample drawings which illustrate the effects described. After hearing your characterizations of the difficulty of this problem, and the hackiness of the solution thus far already, I'm thinking that I might just accept the darkened drawings as good enough for now. I really appreciate your suggestions though, and may come back to try some variations of them at some point.

Comment: @joojaa What does it mean to 'stack views' in this context? I'm not clear on what that means, or if it could be applied to my case, in which I've been using post-processing of the cad-exported images to convert them to line drawings (with edge-detection, etc.).

Comment: Depends on your cad really. But in anycas export one shaded view and one not shaded view an put them on top of eachother. We can only help you withthings you can tell us about.

Comment: Nice with some images. I've tried to see what I could do, but even in Photoshop it would require some manual work to make the contour lines thicker while preserving the shading lines. I can't see how it could be done with a command line tool. You'll have to make manual masks and paint a little.